# How to use tensor.item() ? IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use tensor.item() to convert a 0-dim tensor to a Python number

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, tensor, index-error

Im pretty new to Siamese Neural Networks and recently found [this example](https://innovationincubator.com/siamese-neural-network-with-pytorch-code-example/) and [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FsixLon5Zz3_rFA0xIHzc8Tvnnw8FLr8#scrollTo=EDMURKIHPI7E).

When running the code i get the following error:

> IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use tensor.item() to
>   convert a 0-dim tensor to a Python number

on the line:

```
result=torch.max(res,1)[1][0][0][0].data[0].tolist()
```

I found something about the `tensor.item()` but i really just don't know how to use it here.

EDIT:

```
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset,num_workers=6,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)
accuracy=0
counter=0
correct=0
for i, data in enumerate(test_dataloader,0): 
x0, x1 , label = data
# onehsot applies in the output of 128 dense vectors which is then  converted to 2 dense vectors
output1,output2 = model(x0.to(device),x1.to(device))
res=torch.abs(output1.cuda() - output2.cuda())
label=label[0].tolist()
label=int(label[0])
result=torch.max(res,1)[1][0][0][0].data.item().tolist()
if label == result:
correct=correct+1
counter=counter+1
#   if counter ==20:
#      break

accuracy=(correct/len(test_dataloader))*100
print("Accuracy:{}%".format(accuracy))
```

Thats the code i get the error on.

Comment: Please describe the context of the function call, in your case likely the dimensions and content of `res`. Even though (or especially because) it is a Colab notebook, the Stackoverflow policy of an [mcve] still applies, since those external resources migth eventually be deactivated and then point to dead ends that make the context of the question harder to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this error message says is that you're trying to index into an array which has just one item in it. For example,

```
In [10]: aten = torch.tensor(2)   

In [11]: aten  
Out[11]: tensor(2)

In [12]: aten[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5c40f6ab046a> in <module>
----> 1 aten[0]

IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor.  Use tensor.item() to convert a 0-dim 
tensor to a Python number
```

In the above case, `aten` is a tensor with just a single number in it. So, using an index (or more) to retrieve that number throws the `IndexError`.

The correct way to extract the number(item) out of the tensor is to use `tensor.item()`, here `aten.item()` as in:

```
In [14]: aten.item()
Out[14]: 2
```

Comment: with the notion that at some point item() may be [slow](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/item-before-backward-makes-execution-much-slower/41515)

Comment: When i add the .item() i get another error on the same line:

    result=torch.max(res.item(),1)[1][0][0][0].data[0].tolist()
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars